# importing akka zeromq extension in scala

Tags: macos, scala, akka, akka-zeromq

I'm trying to use zeromq extension in scala but compilation fails with sbt.

```
import akka.zeromq._
```

Here is the error I got;

```
object zeromq is not a member of package akka
```

build.sbt file looks like;

```
name := "Akka Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype (releases)" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.zeromq" %% "zeromq-scala-binding" % "0.0.6"
```

I try to follow installation instructions for osx from zeromq official page.
http://zeromq.org/bindings:scala-binding

```
zeromq version = 2.1.11

scala version = 2.10.2

os = osx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Akka ZeroMQ extension appears to be in its own package. Add this to library dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-zeromq" % "2.2.0"
```